How exactly do you create a skewed Normal Distribution?
I have always heard of skewed probability distributions, but I have always wondered how exactly do created a skewed probability distribution?

For example, the probability density function (PDF) for a standard normal distribution is:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} $$
Reading about how to do this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution), I came across the following transformation
$$ f(x; \alpha) = 2\phi(x)\Phi(\alpha x) $$
Where:

$\phi(x)$ is the PDF of the standard normal distribution
$\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the standard normal distribution
$\alpha$ is the shape parameter that controls the skewness (negative $\alpha$ for left skew)

I tried to expand this:
$$ f(x; \alpha) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\left[1 + \text{erf}\left(\frac{\alpha x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] $$
Where $\text{erf}(x)$ is the error function.

To create a left-skewed normal distribution from a regular normal distribution, it seems that we would choose a negative value for $\alpha$ and apply the transformation above to the standard normal distribution

To create a right-skewed normal distribution from a regular normal distribution, it seems that we would choose a positive value for $\alpha$ and apply the transformation above to the standard normal distribution


Is this the right idea? Is it possible to understand why this transformation results in a skewed normal?

Based on the Probability Integral Transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform), I simulated data from these in R to verify this:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

generate_skewed <- function(n, alpha) {
 
    u <- runif(n)
    

    x <- qnorm(u) + alpha * abs(qnorm(u))
    
    return(x)
}

n <- 10000 

left_skew <- generate_skewed(n, alpha = -1)

non_skew <- generate_skewed(n, alpha = 0)

right_skew <- generate_skewed(n, alpha = 1)

df <- data.frame(
    value = c(left_skew, non_skew, right_skew),
    distribution = rep(c("Left-skewed", "Non-skewed", "Right-skewed"), each = n)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = value, fill = distribution)) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
    facet_wrap(~distribution, ncol = 1) +
    labs(title = "Comparison of Custom Skewed and Non-skewed Distributions",
         subtitle = "Using Probability Integral Transform Method",
         x = "Value",
         y = "Density") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Left-skewed" = "blue", "Non-skewed" = "green", "Right-skewed" = "red")) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")



Several answers here help.

Have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution
